# Como hacer que cuando se duplica un encargo en un web que la fecha del duplicado sea la del dia actual y no la fecha original

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Mi pregunta es cuando tienes un encargo con su fecha de creación.

Si se duplica ese encargo quiero que la fecha de duplicado sea la actual y no la de origen para diferenciarla.

el código seria este donde se duplica el encargo la fecha

```php
private function _duplica_registro($id_encargo_original, $id_encargo_nuevo, $tabla, $campo_nulo) {
        // Obtenemos los registros
        $registros = $this->db->get_where($tabla, ['id_encargo' => $id_encargo_original])->result_array();
        
        // Copiamos los datos
        foreach ($registros as $registro) {
            // Primero, tal cual
            $datos = $registro;
            
            // Cambiamos sólo lo nuevo
            unset($datos[$campo_nulo]);
            $datos['id_encargo'] = $id_encargo_nuevo;
            
            // Algunos detalles según la tabla
            if ($tabla === 'observaciones') {
                // Fecha original de la observación
                $datos['texto_observacion'] = '[Observación duplicada de otro expediente. Fecha original: ' 
                . date('d-m-Y', strtotime($registro['fecha_creacion'])) . '] ' . $registro['texto_observacion'];
            }
            if ($tabla === 'contactos') {
                // Dejamos a todos desmarcado que atendió la visita
                $datos['atendio_visita'] = FALSE;
            }
            /*
             * 20220720 DCG Fecha de subida del fichero igual que el encargo de origen
            if ($tabla === 'encargos_ficheros') {
                // Fecha en que se subieron los archivos
                $datos['fecha_fichero'] = date('Y-m-d'); // Ponemos la fecha en que se crea el registro. No se si quieren la fecha en que se subió originalmente el archivo.
            }
             * 
             */

            // Guarda los datos en la tabla
            $this->db->insert($tabla, $datos);
            
            // Registra el evento
            $this->app_model->actividad_administrador($this->id_administrador, $this->pagina . '/duplica/' . $tabla, 'insert', $datos);
        }
        
        return;
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En donde cambias la fecha?

Comment: Me refiero a que tu tienes un encargo con un nombre, observaciones, fecha en la que se hizo el encargo etc. Bueno pues ahora lo que digo es que si tu ahora duplicas ese encargo en otra fecha distinta a la de origen, deberia salir la fecha actual del duplicado del encargo

Answer (score 0):

Te voy a responder acá porque pondré código y en un comentario no podría.

Comentario del OP

> Me refiero a que tu tienes un encargo con un nombre, observaciones, fecha en la que se hizo el encargo etc. Bueno pues ahora lo que digo es que si tu ahora duplicas ese encargo en otra fecha distinta a la de origen, debería salir la fecha actual del duplicado del encargo

No, si lo que haces es un **SELECT** de un X registro y lo insertas a la misma o a otra tabla. A no ser que tomes la fecha de un "encargo" de un timestamp que lo dudo. Lo que debes hacer es cambiar la fecha de encargo por la fecha de hoy, pero eso no se programará solo, lo debes hacer tu.

Algo así:

```
// Manejo de la Fecha Actual
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
$fecha_actual = date('d/m/Y', time());

private function _duplica_registro($datos) {
    $registros = $this->db->get_where($tabla, ['id_encargo' => $id_encargo_original])->result_array();

    foreach ($registros as $registro) {
        $datos = $registro;

        unset($datos[$campo_nulo]);
        $datos['id_encargo'] = $id_encargo_nuevo;
        $datos['fecha'] = $fecha_actual; // <=== Nueva fecha del registro

        if ($tabla === 'observaciones') {
            $datos['texto_observacion'] = '[Observación duplicada de otro expediente. Fecha original: '
            . date('d-m-Y', strtotime($registro['fecha_creacion'])) . '] ' . $registro['texto_observacion'];
        }
        if ($tabla === 'contactos') {
            $datos['atendio_visita'] = FALSE;
        }

        $this->db->insert($tabla, $datos);

        $this->app_model->actividad_administrador($this->id_administrador, $this->pagina . '/duplica/' . $tabla, 'insert', $datos);
    }
    return;
}
```

Solo comenté la línea que podría ser referencia para que puedas cambiar la fecha. Las dos primeras líneas son solo para que veas de donde sale la variable **$fecha_actual**